# livecharts piechart mvvm databinding

Tags: wpf, livecharts

I am having trouble attempting to perform a seemingly simple series databind on a livecharts piechart.  The error I"m seeing in output is -

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in LiveCharts.dll Object reference not set to an instance of
>   an object.

Here is my binding -

```
<lvc:PieChart LegendLocation="None" Series="{Binding TodayValues}" 
         DataTooltip="{x:Null}">

</lvc:PieChart>
```

And here is my ViewModel property -

```
private SeriesCollection _todayValues;
        public SeriesCollection TodayValues
        {
            get { return _todayValues; }
            set { SetNotifyingProperty(() => TodayValues, ref _todayValues, value); }
        }

        private void LoadInventoryPieCharts()
        {
            _todayValues = new SeriesCollection
            {
                new PieSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double>{ 21 }
                },
                new PieSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double>{ 4 }
                }
            };
}
```

SetNotifyingProperty is just an iplementation of INotifyPropertyChanged and the LoadInventoryPieCharts gets called when the VM is loaded.

Any thoughts on what is missing that is causing a nullreferenceexceptio?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your issue. Please always remember to provide a MCVE when you ask a question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace on this? Because I get the same thing when I try to set the Series of a PieChart programmatically. I'm using v.9.7.0. First lines of stack trace = "at LiveCharts.SeriesAlgorithms.PieAlgorithm.Update() in c:\Users\btord\Documents\Projects\LiveCharts\Core40\SeriesAlgorithms\PieAlgorithm.cs:line 74
   at LiveCharts.ChartUpdater.Update(Boolean restartsAnimations, Boolean force) in c:\Users\btord\Documents\Projects\LiveCharts\Core40\ChartUpdater.cs:line 124"

Comment: unfortunately, i don't.  i've actually abandoned this course as it didnt pan out and requirements change.  if i get a chance to circle back on it, i'll update accordingly.